# Configuring IIS for two Angular apps on domain and subdomain

Tags: iis, deployment

I have some complicated scenario I can't configure.

I need a web.config file to configure IIS to serve 2 Angular apps. The first will run on domain.com and the second on sub.domain.com

The fix which is working now si to put the first app (domain.com) in wwwroot and the second app (sub.domain.com) in a folder inside the first app. The web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>

          <rule name="Redirect subdomain" enabled="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub\.domain\.com$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="subfolder/{R:1}"/>
          </rule>

        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

The problem is that I need to add some url rewriting rules which will apply only to the first app. If I add them to the web.config file then the second app will be redirected to the first app because of the rules I added.

An ideal solution would be something like this

**wwwroot**

- first_app_v1.1
- - ...
- - web.config (add url rewriting rules)
- second_app_v2.1
- - ...
- web.cofig ( if (we are on sub.domain.com) { go to second app } else { go to first app } )

This way the deployment will be safer and if I need to go back do a different version it will be much easier.
I am new to this technology, if there are better ways to do this I would appreciate some resources.

Answer (score 0):

I use asp.net mvc, don't know if you do.

I would simply read which is the incoming domain and, depending on which domain, render the appropriate angular-configured view. Seems easier than messing with `web.config` and URL rewriting. Obviously You would serve the appropriate js files based on which view/angular app You are rendering.

The logic on the server would be minimal. In IIS you would simply point both domains to the same asp.net folder. This solution basically involves creating two SPAs within the context of one asp.net website.

I would be happy to post the code to do this if u are interested.

Comment: The code might help somebody.